# How to trim whitespace in python

Tags: python, whitespace

I have string:

```
lote1 = 'GO, DF, MS'
lote1.strip()
print(lote1)

GO, DF, MS
```

I need:

```
GO,DF,MS
```

Comment: Which do you need, `'GO, DF, MS'` or `'GO,DF,MS'`?  Your post isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
''.join(line.split())
```

Comment: @CristianoPires you're welcome. :) please, accept my answer (or whichever helped you the most) by clicking on the tick button in front of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `lote1.replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 2):

The question is too vague.

Just in case you need just to strip space both at the beginning and the end of comma-delimited strings:

```
> s = "   foo bar bar  baar  ,   foo bar , foo bar bar bar "
> ",".join(x.strip() for x in s.split(","))
'foo bar bar  baar,foo bar,foo bar bar bar'
```

Comment: Funny story, I am the case that just needed to strip whitespace. Thanks for being thorough for the hell of it.